# How to abort processing a sampler when a pre-processor execution is failed?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Is there a way to abort processing a sampler (HTTP Request) when any of the pre-processors execution is failed?

**Scenario:**

- There is a JSR223 Pre-processor associated with an HTTP Request
- The JSON payload (request body) is created dynamically inside the JSR223 Preprocessor.
- The JSON payload is not created successfully at certain times.
- HTTP requests should not be sent when the JSON payload is not created successfully.

I have tried following within a try-catch block of the JSR223 Pre-processor.

```
try {
    //JSON playload creating script 
}catch(anything){
    ctx.setRestartNextLoop(true);
}
```

This does not abort the execution of the current sampler.
Processing JSON payload outside the samplers may not be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function is:

```
ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP)
```

However it won't prevent execution of the current sampler, it will not run the **next sampler** so it makes sense to generate the request body in the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) of the previous request

A more readable solution which will be easier understood by your colleagues would be generating the body in the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and conditionally running the HTTP Request sampler via [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)